# About image in IText 5.2.1

Tags: java, itext

[image]

When you zoom in PDF, text will not be distorted, the image distortion.
How to make the picture enlarged without distortion, But don't vector map.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

the problem that you are facing is about your image's DPI. Most PDF viewers draw the image at a fixed dpi regardless of the image's dpi. My guess is you are using a 150 dpi or so. Try playing with the dpi value to find a good fit for the area you are trying to draw your image into and the size of the original image.

Also make sure your original image is big enough for the area you are trying to cover.